# Resource file is not included when packaging and publishing web role on windows azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-storage

I want to deploy a web role on Windows Azure. The project contains a large resource file (in fact, a dictionary file with extension `.dct`).

After packaging with vs2010, I investigate the `.cspkg` file, no `.dct` files are included in the `approot` sub-directory. What may be the problem and how to solve?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it to Copy Local in the files properties. See this screenshot: [image]

Edited to add: According to @Summer_More_More_Tea it wasn't the Copy Local property but rather setting the [Build Action to 'Content'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx), which specifies the file is not compiled but is included in the output.

Comment: You have my point. My IDE is VS2010, and I didn't find a property named `Copy Local`. Instead, the file is included when I change `Build Acion` from `None` to `Content`. I write down this comment for others' reference. Thank you a lot :)!